# set gdefault Not Working as Expected in Vim

Tags: vim

In my vimrc, I have the line `set gdefault`. This lets me type `:%s/hello/goodbye` to replace all instances of hello with goodbye (don't need the trailing /g at the end). However, I thought that I would also be able to revert to the default behavior (replace one instance at a time) by typing `:%s/hello/goodbye/g`, but even that replaces all instances of hello with goodbye. Could anyone provide any insight as to why I'm getting this behavior? I'm not sure if it's something else in my vimrc, but [here's a link to my vimrc](https://github.com/codyma94/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc)

Comment: Using `'gdefault'` and the `g` flag will only do one replacement per line in a range. I suggest you read `:h 'gdefault'` and `:h [range]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `c` flag to it. It'll ask you to confirm each replacement, like so:

```
:%s/hello/goodbye/gc
```

For more flags offered with `%s` and there usage, check this [link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks! FYI for future readers, only `:%s/hello/goodbye/c` is necessary to confirm each change. Don't need that g

Comment: @Cody: Glad could help, here you can find all the flags for `%s` : `http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace`